# Papa Parse - array to markers

Tags: leaflet, papaparse

This should be a really quick and easy one. Sorry if there is a simple solution. I've read through the documentation but can't figure it out.

I've parsed a CSV using papa-parse.

[image]

```
 var lyrHouses = Papa.parse('src/Houses.csv', {
                header: true,
                download: true,
                dynamicTyping: true,
                skipEmptyLines: true,
                complete: function(results) {
                    console.log(results.data);
                }
            });
```

I would like to manipulate the array further.

How do I..

1. Create markers from the array.
2. Perform further analysis via Turf on said array. ie. I know how to use Turf but do I need to transform the array to L.geoJson?

I thought this would be easy but after an hour, I can't figure out how to use the array properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate through your results and create GeoJSON features/markers from your array.

```
 housesGeoJSON = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [ ]
}

var lyrHouses = Papa.parse('src/Houses.csv', {
                header: true,
                download: true,
                dynamicTyping: true,
                skipEmptyLines: true,
                complete: function(results) {
                    results.data.forEach((house) => {
                        feature = {
                            "type": "Feature",
                            "geometry": {
                              "type": "Point",
                              "coordinates": [house.Longitude, house.Latitude]
                            },
                            "properties": {
                              "Location": house.Location
                            }
                          }
                          marker = L.geoJSON(feature).addTo(map)
                          // Create geojson of all markers push feature to the declared houses geoJSON
                          housesGeoJSON.features.push(feature)
                    })
                }
            });
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you - I'm surprised I didnt find this in my searching as I would think this would be a common question. Cheers